# Arrowkey input vs focus on objects

Tags: c#, .net, focus, arrow-keys, tetris

I'm currently programming my own Tetris in C# and the input with W,A,S,D works. My problem is that I can't use the arrow keys because of the focus on objects (I mean the blue highlighting on the current object). I have a button to end the game at any time and because of that, it won't register my input as controls of the current Tetris block but as navigating through enabled objects like this one button.

Just in case I did something wrong with reading the input:

```
            bool bl = checkCollision();
            if (!bl && !blocked)
            {
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.W || e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
                {
                       //turning the block
                }
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.S || e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
                {
                         //speeding up the falling
                }
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A || e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
                {                    
                        direction = 'l';
                        if (currentY > 0)
                        {
                            if (!blocked)
                            {
                                inpt = true;
                                currentY -= 1;
                                falling();
                            }      
                        }
                }
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D || e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
                {     
                        direction = 'r';
                            if ((currentY + currentBlock.getSize()) < 10)
                            {
                               if (!blocked)
                               {
                                   inpt = true;
                                   currentY += 1;
                                   falling();
                               }                        
                            }
                }         
            }
```

If you are wondering why I check 2 times if blocked is false (blocked is true if the falling method is currently active so it won't for example move down and left simultaneously).

Is there any way so I can deactivate the focus while somebody plays the game? (So I would simply deactivate the focus when somebody presses 'play' and reactivate it if someone presses 'stop' or lost the game.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit: my program is a Windows Forms-App (.Net Framework)

Comment: you need to specify if it's Forms or WPF.

Comment: Oh, totally forgot it, it's a windows form-app (.Net Framework)